# AWS Lambda Handler Naming Convention

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My organization uses the lambda handler naming convention of:
 `lambda.[team_name]-[function_name]`
In an attempt to deploy a cloud formation template with a few lambda functions that are named in this way, but deployment fails due to a syntax error in the definition of the function.

I've tried removing the dashes in the handler name, and this removes the syntax error--but now I don't have permission to work with the lambda function as the handler doesn't follow our naming conventions.

Has anyone dealt with anything like this, what was your workaround?

Comment: The short-term solution is getting whoever manages the IAM restrictions to exempt this one. The longer-term solution is coming up with a new naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't came across this, but if it brakes with that convention your org have to decide on replacing the convention. And who have a `period (.)` as a function name. That's a flag for me.

And for the immediate issue, it is the `IAM role/group` that was assigned to you doesn't have that modified lambda name. So you cannot  do anything with it